# How do I reference an object that is a type in a java map?

Tags: java, collections, hashmap

I am a beginner and am stuck.  I have a Map which is of type String, Object.  Once I have declared it:

```
Map<String, Fish> fishes = new HashMap<String, Fish>();
```

what do I do now.  How do I get my values into the fish object - I am stuck about how to reference the fish object.  I know I should use 'get', but everything I try doesn't work.

Apologies, I know this is simpleton stuff, but help would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Map<String, Fish> fishes = new HashMap<String, Fish>();
```

To get all your fishes...

```
for (String key : fishes.keySet()) {
    Fish fish = fishes.get(key);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First off your declaration is a bit off, it should be:

```
Map <String, Fish>  fishes = new HashMap <String, Fish> ();
```

To add values into it you would have code that looks like

```
Fish trout = new Fish();
fishes.put("trout",trout);
```

To get the Fish at key "trout" you access it with the get like this:

```
fishes.get("trout");
```

Which returns the Fish object at the key "trout"

Answer (score 0):

```
//creating new Fish object - no big deal
Fish fish = new Fish();
//putting fish to map
fishes.put("MyFish", fish);
//getting your fish
Fish myFish = fishes.get("MyFish");
```

Comment: Guys thank you a lot for you help.  When I first found this site I read that a lot of questions go unanswered and I thought I probably wouldn't get anything back.  What you have said really helps.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you may be having some trouble with syntax, try this:

```
Map<String, Fish>  fishes = new HashMap<String, Fish>();
```

After that, you can use `get` and `put` to get items in and out of the HashMap.

[Java HashMap Documentation](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html)